# routes file error in playframework 2.0

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

This is one of the lines in my routes file:

```
GET  /detail controllers.Message.detail(type: String, text: String, page: Integer ?= 0)
```

When I tried to load the page, it highlighted this line and stated "identifier expected but 'type' found.". Now if I changed the parameter from `type: String` to `newType: String`, the page is loading fine.

What is the problem with the word `type`? Are there reserved words in the routes file?

Comment: If you change the word type by the word "epyt", do you still get the error? If so, then i could be a reserverd keyword....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`type` is a Scala keyword. You can't use them in your routes file. See also this ticket: https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/69-compilation-error-when-using-backticked-scala-keywords-on-routes-file